# Словообразовательный разбор слова "сопутствовать"

Tags: словообразование, учебное-задание

Помогите сделать, пожалуйста, словообразовательный разбор слова "сопутствовать".

Comment: @джулия, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

"сопутствовать" - сопровождать в пути. Образовалось от основы ПУТЬ с помощью приставки СО- и сложного суффикса -СТВОВА-.

Значит, приставочно-суффиксальный способ.

Проверяем: нет слова "сопут", нет слова "путствовать", следовательно, приставка и суффикс присоединились одновременно.

Comment: Но в следующий раз пишите свой вариант, на этом сайте не делают домашних заданий,здесь разрешают сложные ситуации,вот в "Ответах" есть рубрика "Домашние задания"- Вам туда, там отвечают.

Comment: сопуть, осталость в прилагательном  спутный (волна, поток), в слове спутник, в топониме польского города Сопот. СО(С) это не приставка -а корень, с объединяющим смыслом.

Comment: существо - суффикса никакого нет, это идет от сложения корней слов сущее и сотворить в виде сокращения обоих. То же и с путь творит. Великие комбинаторы от лингвистики превращают наш язык в формальность придуманных ими правил.

Comment: Ну, не знаю, кто здесь комбинатор, по мне так как раз "народные лингвисты и этимологи"

Comment: А мы говорим о современных словах, а не об истории языка, да и там всё спорно.

Comment: Ну очень здорово, выходит, что народ по барабану, а вся наука - это что, не народ?

Тогда что, это лингвисты и этимологи, отдельная нация? Ну раз народные в кавычках?

Comment: Вы прекрасно знаете, что это  термин http://feb-web.ru/feb/litenc/encyclop/le7/le7-6071.htm    Переделка и переосмысление заимствованного( или исконного) слова по образцу близкого по звучанию слова родного языка, установление между ними смысловых связей на основе чисто внешнего, случайного звукового совпадения, без учета реальных фактов их происхождения, называется в языкознании народной (или ложной) этимологией

Comment: ну и как вас после этого Людмилой величать?

Answer (score 0):

Простите, **Людмила**, но, на мой взгляд, Вы ошиблись.

Слово "сопутствовать" образовалось **суффиксальным** способом от слова "[сопутствие](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/248125/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)".

Comment: Не могу с Вами согласиться.По Тихонову "путь-сопутствовать-сопутствие (устаревшее)". http://www.efremova.info/word/soputstvie.html - .VSbb0dysUQ8/         
Сопутствие- действие по значению гл. сопутствовать (сопровождать) , а не наоборот:  сопутствовать-это что? совершать сопутствие? а сопутствие-это что? сопутить? Может, когда-то и был такой глагол, а сейчас нет, даже сопутствие устарело, но пока употребляется.

Comment: И каким способом Тихонов "образует" слово "сопутствие" из слова "сопутствовать"? "Отрицательно-суффиксальным"?

Слово "со-пут-ств-ие" может быть образовано из слова "путь" путём добавления **простых** приставки (со-) и суффикса (-ств-). Так-же, как, например, "напутствие". Тогда - слово "сопутствовать" образуется из слова "сопутствие" путём добавления **простого** суффикса -ова-. Так-же, как слово "напутствовать".

Всё просто и понятно. Вы же предлагаете "городить огород". Сперва создав слово с применением составного суффикса, а потом - "редуцировав" его до более простого.

Comment: А разве для слова  "сопутствие" при схеме образования "путь - сопутствие" не придется "городить"  СЛОЖНЫЙ СУФФИКС СТВ+ИJ?

Comment: Уважаемый greydog, а "присутствие" - от "присутствовать"? или "присутствовать" -от "присутствие"? Присутствовать- это что значит?осуществлять присутствие? Или всё же по-русски присутствие-результат по действию глагола "присутствовать"?